# Usage of switchMapTo after switchMapTo

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, switchmap

**Expected behavior:**

1) Get all tasks from `taskService.getAllTasks()`;

2) Pass the result tasks to `filterService.addFilterableTasks()`;

3) Get tasks from `filterService.getFilteredTasks()`;

4) Pass the result tasks to `searchService.addTasks()`;

5) Get tasks from `searchService.getBoardFilteredTasks()`.

```
this.taskService.getAllTasks().pipe(
          tap((allTasks: Task[]) => {
              this.filterService.addFilterableTasks(allTasks);
              console.log(allTasks) // (1)
          }),
          switchMapTo(this.filterService.getFilteredTasks()),
          tap((tasks: Task[]) => {
              this.searchService.addTasks(tasks);
              console.log(`passed ${tasks.length} tasks`) // (2)
          }),
          switchMapTo(this.searchService.getBoardFilteredTasks()) // (3)
).subscribe((tasks: Task[]) => {          
          /* get the result tasks and show them on a board */
})
```

**Current behavior:**

*Without line (3):*

line 1 => expected array in the console

line 2 => correct number of passed tasks

*With line (3):*

line 1 and everything further are not triggered. An error says that there are no tasks in `searchService.getBoardFilteredTasks`

**Question:**

Is it allowed to use one `switchMapTo()` after another?

Or is there another way to implement such?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you're calling `switchMapTo(x)` it happens *long before* you subscribe. And `x` is evaluated right there.  Think about it: if I call `foo(2 + 1)`, it will evaluate `2 + 1` to `3` then call `foo(3)`. `switchMapTo(this.searchService.getBoardFilteredTasks())` is doing the same thing. So, if something inside of this call to `this.searchService.getBoardFilteredTasks()` is looking for state that won't be there until the rest of the observable is running, it's going to fail.

You might fix it by using ordinary `switchMap` which will defer the creation of the observable you're switch-mapping to until a value actually arrives:

`switchMap(() => this.searchService.getBoardFilteredTasks())`

**Generally, if you're calling a function and passing it to `switchMapTo`, `mergeMapTo`, etc, you are probably making a mistake. Those are best used with static observable references to avoid confusion**,